# Dovecot not running quota sql query

Tags: mysql, dovecot

I'm trying to configure dovecot to handle quota limits.

I have followed a guide and configure the right steps. I even compared them with our current mailserver.

The problem is, Dovecot doesn't write to the quota2 table in our database. I have checked both the mysql logs and the maillog file (dovecot log location), but I don't see any errors about the quota. All other queries are working perfect. The quota in the users table is also fetched.

Does anyone have a clue? What am I missing?

Dovecot -n output:

```
# 2.0.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.14.35-28.38.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64  ext4
auth_mechanisms = plain login
dict {
  quotadict = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
}
mail_location = maildir:/var/spool/mail/virtual/%d/%n
mail_plugins = quota
mail_privileged_group = mail
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/conf.d/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  quota = dict:user::proxy::quotadict
}
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_ca = </root/ssl/root-cert.pem
ssl_cert = </root/ssl/private-cert.pem
ssl_key = </root/ssl/private-key.pem
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/conf.d/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = quota
}
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = quota imap_quota imap_quota
}
protocol pop3 {
  mail_plugins = quota
  pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
}
```

dovecot-sql.conf.ext:

```
password_query = SELECT email as user, password FROM users WHERE email='%u';

user_query = \
  SELECT CONCAT('/var/spool/mail/virtual/',CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1),'/', \
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1))) AS home, \
  5001 AS uid, \
  5001 AS gid, \
  CONCAT('maildir:storage=',quota) AS quota \
  FROM users WHERE email='%u' \
  AND enabled = '1';
```

dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext:

```
map {
  pattern = priv/quota/storage
  table = quota2
  username_field = username
  value_field = bytes
}
map {
  pattern = priv/quota/messages
  table = quota2
  username_field = username
  value_field = messages
}
```

UPDATE:

Log files (without amavis)

```
May  8 10:03:47 host dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=18369 uid=0 code=kill)
May  8 10:03:47 host dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. bytes=9721/22462
May  8 10:03:47 host dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. bytes=4471/11038
May  8 10:03:47 host dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. bytes=4663/11356
May  8 10:03:47 host dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. bytes=8663/23549
May  8 10:03:48 host dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.0.9 starting up (core dumps disabled)
May  8 10:03:48 host dovecot: ssl-params: Generating SSL parameters
May  8 10:03:50 host dovecot: ssl-params: SSL parameters regeneration completed
May  8 10:03:55 host dovecot: auth: mysql: Connected to 127.0.0.1 (mail)
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<test@jouwweb.email>, method=PLAIN, rip=80.113.202.232, lip=172.31.18.109, mpid=18399, TLS
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib10_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib11_imap_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=maildir:storage=10
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Effective uid=5001, gid=5001, home=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Quota root: name=storage=10 backend=maildir args=
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test, index=, control=, inbox=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<test@jouwweb.email>, method=PLAIN, rip=80.113.202.232, lip=172.31.18.109, mpid=18402, TLS
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib10_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib11_imap_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=maildir:storage=10
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Effective uid=5001, gid=5001, home=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Quota root: name=storage=10 backend=maildir args=
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test, index=, control=, inbox=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<test@jouwweb.email>, method=PLAIN, rip=80.113.202.232, lip=172.31.18.109, mpid=18404, TLS
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib10_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib11_imap_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=maildir:storage=10
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Effective uid=5001, gid=5001,
May  8 10:03:47 host dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=18369 uid=0 code=kill)
May  8 10:03:47 host dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. bytes=9721/22462
May  8 10:03:47 host dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. bytes=4471/11038
May  8 10:03:47 host dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. bytes=4663/11356
May  8 10:03:47 host dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. bytes=8663/23549
May  8 10:03:48 host dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.0.9 starting up (core dumps disabled)
May  8 10:03:48 host dovecot: ssl-params: Generating SSL parameters
May  8 10:03:50 host dovecot: ssl-params: SSL parameters regeneration completed
May  8 10:03:55 host dovecot: auth: mysql: Connected to 127.0.0.1 (mail)
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<test@jouwweb.email>, method=PLAIN, rip=80.113.202.232, lip=172.31.18.109, mpid=18399, TLS
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib10_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib11_imap_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=maildir:storage=10
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Effective uid=5001, gid=5001, home=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Quota root: name=storage=10 backend=maildir args=
May  8 10:04:47 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test, index=, control=, inbox=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<test@jouwweb.email>, method=PLAIN, rip=80.113.202.232, lip=172.31.18.109, mpid=18402, TLS
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib10_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib11_imap_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=maildir:storage=10
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Effective uid=5001, gid=5001, home=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Quota root: name=storage=10 backend=maildir args=
May  8 10:04:49 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test, index=, control=, inbox=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<test@jouwweb.email>, method=PLAIN, rip=80.113.202.232, lip=172.31.18.109, mpid=18404, TLS
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib10_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib11_imap_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=maildir:storage=10
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Effective uid=5001, gid=5001, home=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Quota root: name=storage=10 backend=maildir args=
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test, index=, control=, inbox=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<test@jouwweb.email>, method=PLAIN, rip=80.113.202.232, lip=172.31.18.109, mpid=18406, TLS
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib10_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib11_imap_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=maildir:storage=10
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Effective uid=5001, gid=5001, home=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Quota root: name=storage=10 backend=maildir args=
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test, index=, control=, inbox=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Debug: none: root=, index=, control=, inbox=
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Connect from local
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib10_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Debug: auth input: test@jouwweb.email home=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test uid=5001 gid=5001 quota=maildir:storage=10
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=maildir:storage=10
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427, test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Effective uid=5001, gid=5001, home=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427, test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Quota root: name=storage=10 backend=maildir args=
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427, test@jouwweb.email): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test, index=, control=, inbox=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427, test@jouwweb.email): 9nRZJ46KTFX7RwAAx8Xrpw: msgid=<26D1B8E0-9451-4EEB-B79E-A530F6236DE0@me.com>: saved mail to INBOX
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Disconnect from local: Client quit
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Quota root: name=storage=10 backend=maildir args=
May  8 10:04:51 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test, index=, control=, inbox=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<test@jouwweb.email>, method=PLAIN, rip=80.113.202.232, lip=172.31.18.109, mpid=18406, TLS
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib10_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib11_imap_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap: Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=maildir:storage=10
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Effective uid=5001, gid=5001, home=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Quota root: name=storage=10 backend=maildir args=
May  8 10:04:53 host dovecot: imap(test@jouwweb.email): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test, index=, control=, inbox=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Debug: none: root=, index=, control=, inbox=
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Connect from local
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib10_quota_plugin.so
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Debug: auth input: test@jouwweb.email home=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test uid=5001 gid=5001 quota=maildir:storage=10
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=maildir:storage=10
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427, test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Effective uid=5001, gid=5001, home=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427, test@jouwweb.email): Debug: Quota root: name=storage=10 backend=maildir args=
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427, test@jouwweb.email): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test, index=, control=, inbox=/var/spool/mail/virtual/jouwweb.email/test
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427, test@jouwweb.email): 9nRZJ46KTFX7RwAAx8Xrpw: msgid=<26D1B8E0-9451-4EEB-B79E-A530F6236DE0@me.com>: saved mail to INBOX
May  8 10:06:06 host dovecot: lmtp(18427): Disconnect from local: Client quit
```

If you are interested in the log with amavis includes, check the gist file below:
https://gist.github.com/jordi12100/f14842f724d62a47c570

UPDATE 2 (thanks to Fox): 
The quota is updating. However, the mail doesn't seem to block when I am over my limit. Current limit is 10kb, which I exceeded after I sent a couple of messages. Missing any setting?

Comment: Try to set `mail_debug` to `yes` and post the output here. See http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Logging

Comment: @masegaloeh I've added the output of the log file.

Comment: Thanks, I've trimmed your logs so it doesn't contain many ir-relevant parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little guess based on comparing your configuration to my.

`CONCAT('maildir:storage=',quota) AS quota`
should rather be
`CONCAT('maildir:storage=',quota) AS quota_rule`

I think you are overriding the `quota=` setting from configuration, by per-user entry. (But I am no expert, so really just a guess)

Do not remember why, but my quota query is `concat('*:storage=', quota) as quota_rule`, should that help somehow ...

Edit: I think it gets delivered, because you are using lmtp, but do not have quota enabled for lmtp. You need something like I have:

```
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = quota fts fts_solr sieve
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The quota is updating. However, the mail doesn't seem to block when I am over my limit. Current limit is 10kb, which I exceeded after I sent a couple of messages. Missing any setting?

Comment: @JordiKroon you are welcome. updated my answer. didn't notice that ...